# spring security without form login to use a rest endpoint for authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have researched on this a bit and found the following answers.

1. to use http-basic
2. create a custom handlers[as my search consists of rest endpoint] and without http-basic or form-login config I am getting `No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established.`
3. Use `create-session=stateless`

My Use case:

I have built a Rest endpoint which uses the AuthenticationManager for validating the username and password from a POST request to the endpoint. 
let us for convenience consider the endpoint as `/checkSubscriberLogin`.
Everything works fine. I could do a POST request and get the response as `"message:authenticated"` or `message:user not found` depending on the authenticationProvider.
But Now I want to use only this endpoint and don't want to use either `form-login` or `http-basic` or `create-session=stateless`

Can some one help me. I can add details if I am missing any, please help me.

Comment: It sounds like you're reinventing OAuth2 Password Grant, and you should probably just use that.

Comment: So there is no way using the spring-security without form-login except for using oauth2? I am asking because I am working on a e-commerce website with hybris framework and the user details schema is so far defined and hard to introduce client id and client secret schema in the database. When I said it is not possible to use to spring security without form-login or http-basic the question asked why we cant we use. And I have no answer for that. I am trying to find since 2 days and no luck

Comment: You *can* but haven't demonstrated a good reason why you *should*. What's different about your setup that form-login doesn't do what you need? (And the "client" schema is completely separate from `UserDetails`.)

Comment: So by doing without form-login, our front-end wants to do a Ajax call instead of depending on Jsp. And also we have a plan to port this extension in Hybris to be moved in future. we are actively working on it to decommission Hybris.  So our front end want to be as modular as possible so we can host our front-end and back-end on two different independent servers. So Back-end would be only serving as a REST api